How to change CHeaderCtrl height (multiline height)
I try to develope multiline (doubleline) header - CHeaderCtrl of the CListCtrl. I am not able to change the heigth of the header.
How I can change the heigth without changing the font?
Code of doubleline CHeaderCtrl:
"dlg.h" file
 #pragma once
#include "resource.h"
#include "framework.h"
#include <map>
#include <set>


using namespace std;

//My own header for multiline header
class CMyHeaderCtrl : public CHeaderCtrl
{
public:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()

    void OnCustomDraw(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult);

    void OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point);
};

class CMFCtestDlg : public CDialogEx
{
    // Construction
public:
    CMFCtestDlg(CWnd *pParent = nullptr);   // standard constructor
    ~CMFCtestDlg() { }

    // Dialog Data
#ifdef AFX_DESIGN_TIME
    enum { IDD = IDD_MFC_TEST_DIALOG };
#endif
protected:
    map<int, LPCTSTR> m_mapOfTab{{0,L"Nula"},{1,L"Jedna"},{2,L"Dva"}};

public:
    CListCtrl m_cListCtrl;      // First list control
    CMyHeaderCtrl m_myHeaderCtrl;


protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange *pDX);    // DDX/DDV support

    // Implementation
protected:
    HICON m_hIcon;

    // Generated message map functions
    virtual BOOL OnInitDialog();
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
    CMenu m_SplitMenu;
    CMenu m_SplitSubMenu;

public:
    void OnHeaderDropDown(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult);
};

"dlg.cpp" file
#include "pch.h"
#include "framework.h"
#include "MFC_test.h"
#include "MFC_testDlg.h"
#include "afxdialogex.h"

#include "resource.h"


#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif

#define _MAJU_PRG_NAME L"Majklův řez"

// CMFCtestDlg dialog
CMFCtestDlg::CMFCtestDlg(CWnd *pParent /*=nullptr*/)
    : CDialogEx(IDD_MFC_TEST_DIALOG, pParent)
{
    m_hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDR_MAINFRAME);
    m_SplitMenu.LoadMenu(IDR_MENU);
}

void CMFCtestDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange *pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_LIST, m_cListCtrl);

}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMFCtestDlg, CDialogEx)
    ON_NOTIFY(HDN_DROPDOWN, IDC_LIST, &CMFCtestDlg::OnHeaderDropDown)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


#define ID_MENU_ITEM1 35600
#define ID_MENU_ITEM2 35601

BOOL CMFCtestDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();

    m_cListCtrl.InsertColumn(0, L"Column 1", LVCFMT_CENTER, 100);
    m_cListCtrl.InsertColumn(1, L"FirstLine\nSecLin", LVCFMT_CENTER, 150);

    CHeaderCtrl *pHeaderCtrl = m_cListCtrl.GetHeaderCtrl();
    if(pHeaderCtrl)
    {
        m_myHeaderCtrl.SubclassWindow(pHeaderCtrl->GetSafeHwnd());

        pHeaderCtrl->ModifyStyle(0, pHeaderCtrl->GetStyle() | HDS_BUTTONS);
        // Modify the header item style to include the split button style
        HDITEM item;
        item.mask = HDI_FORMAT;
        //item.iItem = 0; // Index of the header item you want to modify
        pHeaderCtrl->GetItem(1, &item);
        item.fmt |= HDF_SPLITBUTTON;

        pHeaderCtrl->SetItem(1, &item);
        RECT rect;
        pHeaderCtrl->GetClientRect(&rect);
        //  rect.bottom += rect.bottom - rect.top; //Resize heigth of the Header to double heigth
        rect.bottom += 50;
        pHeaderCtrl->SetWindowPos(0, rect.left, rect.top, rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top, 0);
        //double headerHeight = rect.bottom - rect.top;
    }

    CString csTxt;
    map<int, LPCTSTR>::const_iterator it = m_mapOfTab.begin();
    for(int i = 0; it != m_mapOfTab.end(); ++it, ++i)
    {
        csTxt.Format(L"%i", it->first);
        m_cListCtrl.InsertItem(i, csTxt.GetString());
        m_cListCtrl.SetItemText(i, 1, it->second);
    }

    return TRUE;
}




void CMFCtestDlg::OnHeaderDropDown(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    LPNMHEADER phdr = reinterpret_cast<LPNMHEADER>(pNMHDR);

    // Get the header control
    CHeaderCtrl *pHeaderCtrl = m_cListCtrl.GetHeaderCtrl();

    if(pHeaderCtrl != nullptr && phdr->iItem >= 0)
    {
        // Calculate the drop-down button rectangle
        CRect rcItem;
        pHeaderCtrl->GetItemRect(phdr->iItem, &rcItem);

        // Get the position of the drop-down arrow button
        CPoint point(rcItem.left, rcItem.bottom); // Show menu below the header item
        pHeaderCtrl->ClientToScreen(&point); // Convert to screen coordinates

        // Create and display the context menu

        // Track the popup menu (display it at the arrow location)
        m_SplitMenu.GetSubMenu(0)->TrackPopupMenu(TPM_LEFTALIGN | TPM_RIGHTBUTTON, point.x, point.y, this);
    }
}

////////// CMyHeaderCtrl

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyHeaderCtrl, CHeaderCtrl)
    ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT(NM_CUSTOMDRAW, &CMyHeaderCtrl::OnCustomDraw)
    ON_WM_LBUTTONDOWN()
    ON_WM_PAINT()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


void CMyHeaderCtrl::OnCustomDraw(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    LPNMCUSTOMDRAW pNMCD = reinterpret_cast<LPNMCUSTOMDRAW>(pNMHDR);

    if(pNMCD->dwDrawStage == CDDS_PREPAINT)
    {
        *pResult = CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW;  // Request item draw notifications
    }
    else if(pNMCD->dwDrawStage == CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT)
    {
        *pResult = CDRF_SKIPDEFAULT;  // Skip default drawing

        // Set up the device context
        CDC *pDC = CDC::FromHandle(pNMCD->hdc);
        CRect rect = pNMCD->rc;
        int itemIndex = static_cast<int>(pNMCD->dwItemSpec);

        // Set background color
        pDC->FillSolidRect(&rect, RGB(240, 240, 240));

        // Draw two lines of text
        HDITEM hdItem;
        TCHAR text[256];
        hdItem.mask = HDI_TEXT;
        hdItem.pszText = text;
        hdItem.cchTextMax = sizeof(text) / sizeof(TCHAR);
        GetItem(itemIndex, &hdItem);

        CString headerText(hdItem.pszText);

        // Split text by newline character "\n"
        CString topText, bottomText;
        AfxExtractSubString(topText, headerText, 0, '\n');
        AfxExtractSubString(bottomText, headerText, 1, '\n');

        // Calculate positions for two lines of text
        rect.bottom += 5;
        CRect rectTop = rect;
        CRect rectBottom = rect;

        rectTop.bottom = rect.top + rect.Height() / 2;
        rectBottom.top = rectTop.bottom;

        // Draw the first and second line of text
        CHeaderCtrl *pHeaderCtrl = dynamic_cast<CHeaderCtrl *>(CWnd::FromHandle(pNMCD->hdr.hwndFrom));
        HDITEM item;
        item.mask = HDI_FORMAT;
        pHeaderCtrl->GetItem(pNMCD->dwItemSpec, &item);
        UINT uHdFormat = DT_LEFT;
        if(item.fmt & LVCFMT_RIGHT)
            uHdFormat = DT_RIGHT;
        else if(item.fmt & LVCFMT_CENTER)
            uHdFormat = DT_CENTER;

        pDC->DrawText(topText, &rectTop, uHdFormat | DT_VCENTER | DT_SINGLELINE);
        pDC->DrawText(bottomText, &rectBottom, uHdFormat | DT_VCENTER | DT_SINGLELINE);

        if(item.fmt & HDF_SPLITBUTTON)
        {
            rect.left = rect.right - 16;
            DrawFrameControl(pDC->m_hDC, &rect, DFC_SCROLL, DFCS_SCROLLDOWN);
        }
    }
}

//Split Button
#define ID_OPTION1 32500
#define ID_OPTION2 32501

void CMyHeaderCtrl::OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    // Perform a hit-test to find the header item at the click position
    HDHITTESTINFO hitTestInfo = {0};
    hitTestInfo.pt = point;
    int nItem = SendMessage(HDM_HITTEST, 0, (LPARAM) &hitTestInfo);

    // Check if the click was on a split button
    if(nItem >= 0 && (hitTestInfo.flags & HHT_ONHEADER))
    {
        HDITEM hdItem;
        hdItem.mask = HDI_FORMAT;
        if(GetItem(nItem, &hdItem) && (hdItem.fmt & HDF_SPLITBUTTON))
        {
            CRect itemRect;
            if(!GetItemRect(nItem, &itemRect))
                return CHeaderCtrl::OnLButtonDown(nFlags, point);

            // Define an approximate width for the split button icon (e.g., 16 pixels)
            const int iconWidth = 16;

            // Calculate the area on the far right where the icon would be
            CRect iconRect = itemRect;
            iconRect.left = iconRect.right - iconWidth;

            // Check if the click point falls within the icon area
            if(iconRect.PtInRect(point))
            {
                // Show context menu or handle the split button click
                CMenu menu;
                menu.CreatePopupMenu();
                menu.AppendMenu(MF_STRING, ID_OPTION1, _T("Option 1"));
                menu.AppendMenu(MF_STRING, ID_OPTION2, _T("Option 2"));

                ClientToScreen(&point);
                menu.TrackPopupMenu(TPM_LEFTALIGN | TPM_RIGHTBUTTON, point.x, point.y, this);

                return; // Stop further processing
            }
        }
    }

    // Call base class for default behavior if it wasn't a split button click
    CHeaderCtrl::OnLButtonDown(nFlags, point);
}


Try calling SetWindowPos() on initialization. Other notes: 1. Custom draw and owner-drawn items is not the same thing, 2. I would avoid using those "from handle" MFC routines; they create a "temporary" (?) C++ object and I'm not sure about proper bookkeeping; the "wrapped" Win32 function(s) is usually easy to call, you just need to pass the window or DC handle.

Thanks, I use "FromHandle" only for actual properties reading. I think, it shouldn't cause problem. What do you mean by usually easy using Win32 function? I am not WinAPI professional :-(

See the code of CMFCListCtrl for reference, it is included.

I tried SetWindowPos(). Header will resize, but rows of CListCtrl doesnot move. Header hide (overlap) first row of CLIst Ctrl.....

MFC is to a large extend a "thin wrap" of Win32 API, in many cases way too thin I would say. It's usually easy to call the "wrapped" Win32 function, instead of creating a temporary MFC object. For example, if you have a HDC, instead of calling CDC *pDC=CDC::FromHandle(hDC) and then pDC->DrawText(text, &rct...), it is nearly as easy to call DrawText(hDC, text...) instead - avoids that FromHandle() call (OK a minor point, and not what you are asking here). As for the problem with SetWindowPos(), I tried but couldn't make it any taller. Could you post some code?

I posted there whole code. If I used original CListCtrl class, first row ovelap a part of header. Before I used my own CListCtrl and there overlap header first row. But the problem is the same - how to move first line down, when I need higher header.
